# Errors with forward declarations in cpp

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, visitor-pattern

I am trying to use a visitor 'BehaviorVisitor' which has a method for each type of 'Flower' such as 'Sunflower'. I keep getting this error from BehaviorVisitor:

```
error: variable has incomplete type 'Sunflower'
        void visitVoidSunflower(Sunflower sunflower, const Garden& garden){
```

I have forward declared Sunflower before BehaviorVisitor.

This is my my Flower and BehaviorVisitor interface which is in the .h file:

```
class BehaviorVisitor;

class Flower{
    public:
        Flower();

        Flower(Location _location, Color _color) : rootGrowth(0), height(0), bloom(0), location(_location.getRow(), _location.getColumn()), color{_color}  { }

        //Flower(const Flower&) = delete;
        //Flower(Flower&&) = delete;
        virtual ~Flower() = default;
        //Flower& operator=(const Flower&) = delete;
        Flower& operator=(Flower&&) = delete;


        Location getLocation() const;
        Color getColor();
        Bloom getBloom();
        Height getHeight();
        RootGrowth getRootGrowth();

        void grow(const Garden& garden);
        std::unique_ptr<Flower> spread(const Garden& garden);


        RootGrowth rootGrowth;
        Height height;
        Bloom bloom;

        void acceptVoidReturn(BehaviorVisitor &bv, const Garden& garden){
            return acceptVoidImpl(bv, garden);
        }

        std::unique_ptr<Flower> acceptFlowerReturn(BehaviorVisitor &bv, const Garden& garden){
            return acceptFlowerImpl(bv, garden);
        }

    private:
        Location location;
        Color color;
        virtual void acceptVoidImpl(BehaviorVisitor &bv, const Garden& garden) = 0;
        virtual std::unique_ptr<Flower> acceptFlowerImpl(BehaviorVisitor &bv, const Garden& garden) = 0;
        
};


class Sunflower;

//Visitor interface
class BehaviorVisitor{
    public:
        BehaviorVisitor();
        BehaviorVisitor(const BehaviorVisitor&) = delete;
        BehaviorVisitor(BehaviorVisitor&&) = delete;
        virtual ~BehaviorVisitor() = default;
        BehaviorVisitor& operator=(const BehaviorVisitor&) = delete;
        BehaviorVisitor& operator=(BehaviorVisitor&&) = delete;

        
        
        void visitVoidSunflower(Sunflower sunflower, const Garden& garden){
            return visitVoidImpl(sunflower, garden);
        }
       

        std::unique_ptr<Flower> visitFlowerSunflower(Sunflower sunflower, const Garden& garden){
            return visitFlowerImpl(sunflower, garden);
        }
        


    private:
        void visitVoidImpl(Sunflower flower, const Garden& garden);
        
        std::unique_ptr<Flower> visitFlowerImpl(Sunflower flower, const Garden&);
        
        
};
```

This is the implementation Sunflower in the .cpp file:

```
class Sunflower final: public Flower{
    public:
        Sunflower(Location location, Color color) : Flower(location, color){ }
    private:
        void acceptVoidImpl(BehaviorVisitor &bv, const Garden& garden) override {
            bv.visitVoidSunflower(*this, garden);
        }
        std::unique_ptr<Flower> acceptFlowerImpl(BehaviorVisitor &bv, const Garden& garden ) override {
            return bv.visitFlowerSunflower(*this, garden);
        }
};
```

The thing is, I tried putting  the full class Sunflower before BehaviorVisitor in the .h file. I have already forward declared BehavorVisitor before Flower in my code, but I get the error from Sunflower:

```
error: variable has incomplete type 'BehaviorVisitor'
        void acceptVoidImpl(BehaviorVisitor &bv, const Garden& garden) override {
```

So the sunflower uses a BehaviourVisitor and the BehaviorVisitor uses a Sunflower but this should work since that's what the visitor pattern does.
How do I solve this?

Comment: Forward declarations are only useful for pointer and reference types, they aren't sufficient for copy-by-value parameters.

Comment: When passing a parameter by value, the complete type is required. When passing a parameter by reference or by pointer, a forward declaration will suffice.

Comment: Ok, passing it by reference worked!